# MVC3: Controller action that doesn't refresh session

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create and action that returns whether or not the user's session has expired. The problem is that requesting any action will refresh the user's session timeout. So, I need this action to NOT refresh the timeout.

Is there some way to make a controller action that has access to the session, but does not refresh the timeout?

Comment: Just an untested idea, do controllers decorated with [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)] refresh a session's timeout? If not, maybe you can create another controller that does the check.

Comment: It would seem that they do not. However, Session is null which means I can't check whether the session is still active. That is unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Without knowing your context... Could you just send the time the session will expire with each request, and instead of hitting the action, just check the time client-side? Less accurate, but it might do if you don't find a better solution.

Comment: This is actually similar to what we are doing. However, we are running into problems if the user has multiple tabs open (tabs share session in this application). We need a check like this to ensure that multiple tabs remain in sync. The end result will be a combination of client-side and server-side checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. We built an http module to read the forms auth ticket which could be accessed at `site.com/.formsauthticket`. By handling it at this level, it did not trigger the session at all. I'm afraid I cannot provide code here but we set the module to return the number of milliseconds till the session expired. We then used this number to make some client-side timers.

We based our solution on an answer to a different question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234421/54392). Hope this helps someone else!